# A Study in Effective Sound Design Vol 2: Tangled

Tags: sound-design

I just finished watching this movie:

What an amazing job on the sound design.

The score was extremely good.

The ambiences were top notch.

I wish I had that many good horse SFX to draw from because the horse was detailed and you got every bit of emotion out of it.

The detail of the chameleon effects were as exacting as R2-D2. I wish I knew how to make emotion like that for a mute character that well with sound alone!

The comedic timing was awesome.

One detail I noticed which I wish I could ask the sound designer if that was his intent because it's what I got from it was in the fight scene in the quarry, when the main character Flynn gets hit by the big horse and drops his frying pan of a weapon and it goes dead silent and the pause is long enough so you hear nothing but the pan hit the ground, it makes the perfect "uh oh" pitch which added to the comic "uh oh" moment it was because here was the main character suddenly without a weapon. What a perfect use of sound design to forward the story - was it pitched that way to make the "uh oh" sound?

Anyway, the production value of this movie was just awesome and I think it will be a Disney classic right up there with any of the Pixar films and earlier animated films.

- Ryan

Answer (score 1):

I saw this in the theater and I'd have to agree. The sound effects, music and mix were amazing. Everything was emotive, well placed and there for a reason. Nothing was done to excess, just enough to suit it's purpose.

Considering the frying pan was such a key element and they made a joke out of it a few times I'm pretty sure it was intentional.

Comment: Yeah - brilliant idea. :)